# Bug in passing values in sql query with python

Tags: python, mysql, database, debugging

I am trying to make a social media clone with customtkinter framework and mysql database in python. So, for adding a post I used the execute() function of the connect() function of mysql.connector module to insert the values.

```
import mysql.connector

AddPost_conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="codegram")
AddPost_conn_cursor = AddPost_conn.cursor()

AddPost_conn_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO post(sno,user_id,post_id,post_content) VALUES (2,1234567890,123456789156,'Hello man!')")
AddPost_conn.commit()
AddPost_conn.close()
```

But when I execute the above code, it shows an error.

```
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Here, the column post_id is a primary key constraint. I have no idea how the value of post_id is changing while executing the code.
Can someone help me out with this???

Comment: It seems like the given value is too big and overflow occurs.  Note that 2147483647 in hex is 0x7FFFFFFF which is the maximum value of signed 32-bit integer.

Comment: The above exception will be raised if *strict SQL mode is enabled* and more than one records with such big `post_id` are inserted. See [Out-of-Range and Overflow Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. I fixed the error by changing the table description. Changed the post_id datatype from int to longint.